# Increasing and decreasing text size of WKWebView on macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa, webkit, wkwebview

The old [WebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/webview) on macOS has a built in [makeTextSmaller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/webview/1408520-maketextsmaller) and [makeTextLarger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/webview/1408492-maketextlarger) method. The WKWebView on macOS doesn't have these methods. I am working on transitioning my app to WKWebView and I would like to retain this feature. How can I increase and decrease the text size in a WKWebView on macOS? This is a native Mac app written in Objective-C, not a Mac Catalyst app.

Comment: @Olha please elaborate on this. There is webkit-text-size-adjust for Safari on iOS, but on macOS that does not exist.

Comment: @TAKeanice Well, currently I'm doing this with resetting the property `font-size` for `body` tag in CSS. But this is iOS. Sorry for untested guesses.

Comment: @Olha nothing to excuse for! I guess (!) the `font-size` property should work on macOS as well, but it does not actually do the same as makeTextLarger or makeTextSmaller, especially when the property is overridden for an element. The working solution should _scale_ the font sizes for all text.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Safari still supports making text bigger and smaller (holding Option key when opening the View menu shows these commands), so there must be some way. Even a private API would work for me.

Comment: @keeluu Unfortunately I did not find a solution.

Comment: We used private Webkit methods in Vienna: https://github.com/ViennaRSS/vienna-rss/blob/b408b776639e982a939544d12b5ef110efd94989/Vienna/Sources/Main%20window/WKWebView%2BPrivate.h#L29

Answer (score 1):

We solved that issue in [Vienna](https://www.vienna-rss.com) by declaring a header that gives us access to the internal (private) method `setTextZoomFactor` and the boolean property `supportsTextZoom`.

See our [WKWebView+Private.h](https://github.com/ViennaRSS/vienna-rss/blob/master/Vienna/Sources/Main%20window/WKWebView%2BPrivate.h) as well as everything below [line 182 of our CustomWKWebView](https://github.com/ViennaRSS/vienna-rss/blob/b408b776639e982a939544d12b5ef110efd94989/Vienna/Sources/Main%20window/CustomWKWebView.swift#L182) class.

Comment: This has to be the accepted answer. Thank you for discovering this.